# CodeIgniter 3.1.7 - Class 'MY_Controller' not found error occurred only on my server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in
>   /www/panel/application/controllers/Posts.php on line 3
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'MY_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: controllers/Posts.php
>
> Line Number: 3
>
> Backtrace:

subclass_prefix config is:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

MY_Controller.php is placed on application/core with the filename correctly spelled: MY_Controller.php

I didn't have this problem when I was developing the site on localhost. This error only occurred on my server.

I have tried to google for solution but I didn't find anything helpful.

What can it went wrong? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What’s the exact error you’re getting?

Comment: I have updated it in my question. Please check it out.

Comment: What about the class `class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {}` is that correct

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the controller `Posts` is extending `MY_Controller` which is a valid approach but one that CodeIgniter has a hard time dealing with because of the way CI searches for class files.

There are many ways of making this work. A good description and discussion of the various methods can be found [HERE](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-tutorials/no-more-my_controller-how-you-can-create-more-than-one-base-controller/).

The most simple solution is to explicitly include the `MY_Controller` file.

```
include_once(APPPATH.'core/MY_Controller.php');

class Posts extends MY_Controller {
```

My preference is to inject an autoload function using hooks. If you want to see the details of that let me know. The link provided above also shows this solution.

Comment: If its just `MY_Controller` and you don't have any other controllers in `/core` then you shouldn't even have to do the include. Even your link shows that (way 0). I also do it that way and don't have to include anything. It just gets more complex when you have more `base` controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the filename and the class name are both of the same case: "My" vs "my" vs "MY", and match your config.

Different file systems treat case sensitivity in file names differently, which can cause issues with things working on localhost vs other servers.

Comment: I have checked the filename and the class name are both of the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Blame me for my pain!

Just in case it helps someone, this is how I solved it - I erroneously put the `MY_Controller` file in a wrong directory. Putting it inside `/application/core` FIXED this dreaded error.

I too fell in this labyrinth and wasted precious hours while CI documentation and SO posts screamed at me with the preferred way to auto load it, which is pretty straight forward and simple.